# Python multiprocessing - logging.FileHandler object raises PicklingError

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pickle

It seems that handlers from the `logging` module and `multiprocessing` jobs do not mix:

```
import functools
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp

logger = logging.getLogger( 'myLogger' )
handler = logging.FileHandler( 'logFile' )

def worker( x, handler ) :
    print x ** 2

pWorker = functools.partial( worker, handler=handler )

#
if __name__ == '__main__' :
    pool = mp.Pool( processes=1 )
    pool.map( pWorker, range(3) )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Out:

```
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed
```

If I replace `pWorker` be either one of the following methods, no error is raised

```
# this works
def pWorker( x ) :
    worker( x, handler )

# this works too
pWorker = functools.partial( worker, handler=open( 'logFile' ) )
```

I don't really understand the `PicklingError`. Is it because objects of class `logging.FileHandler` are not pickable? (I googled it but didn't find anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileHandler` object internally uses a `threading.Lock` to synchronize writes between threads. However, the `thread.lock` object returned by `threading.Lock` can't be pickled, which means it can't be sent between processes, which is required to send it to the child via `pool.map`.

There is a section in the `multiprocessing` docs that talks about how logging with `multiprocessing` works [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#logging). Basically, you need to let the child process inherit the parent process' logger, rather than trying to explicitly pass loggers or handlers via calls to `map`.

Note, though, that on Linux, you can do this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger( 'myLogger' )


def worker(x):
    print handler
    print x **2 

def initializer(handle):
    global handler
    handler = handle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = logging.FileHandler( 'logFile' )
    #pWorker = functools.partial( worker, handler=handler )
    pool = Pool(processes=4, initializer=initializer, initargs=(handler,))
    pool.map(worker, range(3))
    pool.close()
    pool.join
```

`initializer`/`initargs` are used to run a method once in each of the pool's child processes as soon as they start. On Linux this allows the handler to be into the child via inheritance, thanks to the way `os.fork` works. However, [this won't work on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows); because it lacks support for `os.fork`, it would still need to pickle `handler` to pass it via `initargs`.